# Feedback for puzzle i made up

Tags: word, puzzle-creation, word-ladder

So I made this puzzle where you have words that branch off into other words. For example:

> [image]

The blue letters you take and move it on to the next blank space, still putting it in order:

> For example, F**UN** and **R**AM would get RUN, not URN, UNR, NUR, RNU or NRU.

Here is the complete puzzle:

> [image]

Tell me your feedback in the comments, and post your answer in the answers.

Comment: I suppose it's a little bit unclear what the exact mechanism for color changes between the letters is. Also, how did the words go from 3 letters to 4 letters - that doesn't seem like a conventional [tag:word-ladder]?

Comment: From the explanation, the word on the right will be `FED` and its last two letters are shown at the bottom as `ED`. So do the other two letters at the bottom form two of the letters on the left, making the first word on the left either `*AP` or `AP*` ?

Comment: What is the connection between the left and right halves of the puzzle? I can see that the word below `FOE` must be `*EE`, and that the word above `MAD` must be `RO*` but how do you get the `*` letters from the other half of the diagram?

Comment: Looks like an interesting idea. Are you asking for us to solve it too? Or has this been solved previously?

Comment: Visually, I'd swap the blue and the black or choose a different colour. The black pops more than the chosen blue.

Answer (score 4):

Bar the unclearness of the puzzle itself, here's a potential solution:

> ```
>          NAE FOE
>         /       \
>      NAY         FEE
>     /   \       /   \
>    /     SAY SEE     \
> NAP                   FED
> \  \     YUM ROB     /  /
>  \  \   /       \   /  /
>   \  YUP         ROD  /
>    \    \       /    /
>     \    MAP MAD    /
>      \____     ____/
>           \   / 
>          _AP+_ED
> ```

Here're the assumptions I made:

> 1. Collisions between blue letters and normal letters break in favor of blue
>  2. Collisions between purple letters and other letters break in favor of purple
>  3. In collisions between letters of equal tier ($purple > blue > normal$), either may be chosen
>  4. For the final selection, the outermost tiles select their last 2 letters
>  5. Purple letters may only be present in the outermost two words and the final answer